# Magento 2 multiplication cron jobs

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have problem with CRON JOBS, I have install amasty_cronschedule module to lookup all executive jobs (is view to cron_schedule table). I noticed that Magento multiplicate all jobs on the same  time.  I paste two examples job but I see all job is multiplicate. I main cronjob i have only one Magento job line. Please tell where looking a solve for this situation. I notice is my cron_schedule  table is larging minute by minute  a lot of records and my custom cron jobs is not always run properly.

Ex.

```
226516  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:25:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:25:04 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:25:04 PM

226517  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:26:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:26:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:26:02 PM

226518  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:27:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:27:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:27:02 PM

226519  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:28:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:28:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:28:02 PM

226520  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:29:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:29:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:29:02 PM

226521  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:30:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:30:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:30:03 PM

226522  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:31:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:31:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:31:02 PM

226523  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:32:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:32:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:32:02 PM

226524  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:33:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:33:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:33:02 PM

226526  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:34:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:34:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:34:02 PM

226527  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:35:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:35:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:35:02 PM

226528  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:36:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:36:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:36:03 PM

226529  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:37:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:37:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:37:03 PM

226530  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:38:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:38:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:38:03 PM

226531  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:39:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:39:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:39:03 PM

226532  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:40:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:40:04 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:40:04 PM

226533  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:41:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:41:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:41:02 PM

226534  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:42:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:42:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:42:02 PM

226535  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:43:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:43:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:43:02 PM

226536  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:44:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:44:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:44:02 PM

226850  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:45:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:45:04 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:45:04 PM

226851  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:46:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:46:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:46:02 PM

226852  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:47:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:47:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:47:02 PM

226853  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:48:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:48:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:48:02 PM

226854  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:49:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:49:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:49:03 PM

226855  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:50:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:50:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:50:03 PM

226856  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:51:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:51:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:51:02 PM

226857  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:52:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:52:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:52:03 PM

226858  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:53:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:53:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:53:02 PM

226859  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:54:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:54:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:54:02 PM

226860  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:55:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:55:04 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:55:04 PM

226861  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:56:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:56:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:56:02 PM

226862  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:57:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:57:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:57:02 PM

226863  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:58:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:58:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:58:02 PM

226864  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:40:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:59:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:59:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:59:03 PM

227145  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:00:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:00:04 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:00:04 PM

227146  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:01:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:01:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:01:02 PM

227147  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:02:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:02:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:02:02 PM

227148  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:03:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:03:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:03:02 PM

227149  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:04:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:04:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:04:03 PM

227150  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:05:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:05:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:05:02 PM

227151  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:06:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:06:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:06:02 PM

227152  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:07:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:07:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:07:02 PM

227153  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:08:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:08:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:08:03 PM

227154  sales_send_order_shipment_emails    
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:55:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:09:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:09:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 8:09:03 PM
```

Another ex.

```
226580  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:25:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:25:04 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:25:04 PM

226581  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:26:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:26:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:26:02 PM

226582  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:27:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:27:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:27:02 PM

226583  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:28:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:28:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:28:02 PM

226584  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:29:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:29:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:29:02 PM

226585  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:30:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:30:04 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:30:04 PM

226586  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:31:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:31:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:31:02 PM

226587  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:32:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:32:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:32:02 PM

226588  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:33:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:33:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:33:02 PM

226589  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:34:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:34:02 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:34:02 PM

226590  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:35:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:35:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:35:03 PM

226591  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:36:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:36:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:36:03 PM

226592  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:37:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:37:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:37:03 PM

226593  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:38:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:38:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:38:03 PM

226594  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:39:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:39:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:39:03 PM

226595  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:40:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:40:04 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:40:04 PM

226596  inventory_in_store_pickup_sales_send_order_notified_emails  
SUCCESS
Mar 6, 2023 7:25:03 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:41:00 PM  Mar 6, 2023 7:41:02 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any duplicate cron jobs in your system, as this can cause multiple instances of the same cron job to run simultaneously. Use 'amasty_cronschedule' module to check for duplicate cron jobs and remove them.

Comment: HI, thanks for reply. I checked main cron jobs and all looks good. I have one job for main instance magento and another job for dev instance. On the Amasty Cron Schedule i don't have duplicate jobs.

Comment: Another possibility ,  Check that any extensions you are using are compatible with your Magento version and are not causing any conflicts with your cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

**Run your custom cron and check :**
php n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run custom-cron-name

**How to Install and Use n98-magerun2**
Read Blog : https://www.wagento.com/how-to-install-and-use-n98-magerun2-to-manage-magento-2-websites/

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I use n98 to test all my custom CRON job and All my custom jobs are executed correctly by n98